# How do I add a transition to this rollover?

Tags: css

How do I add a transition to this rollover?

Here is my css so far:

```
.img-container {
  width: 401px;
  height: 267px;
  position: relative;
}

.img-container:hover .square-icon {
  display: block;
}

.square-icon {
  opacity: .5;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: url(images/zoom-icon.png) center center no-repeat; 
  background-color: #FF3860;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:none;
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<div class="img-container">
  <img alt="lorem" width="401" height="267" src="images/450-300-13.png">
  <div class="square-icon"></div>
</div>
```

I know I need to add:

```
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
```

But I'm not sure where to add it?

Comment: Add this in jsfiddle so as to get an idea of what you really want.
Normally we add transition to the desired element ot class asssciated with the element.
For eg. if you want to add it to the square-icon class it's like
.square-icon {transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;}

Comment: Yes that is what I thought but adding it to that class does not work.. @Kapilgopinath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the two states (normal and hover) of .square-icon to have different levels of opacity and then you can transition on opacity.

See my jsBin demo [here](http://jsbin.com/AtoJuqo/2/edit?html,css,output)

```
.img-container:hover .square-icon {
  opacity: 1; 
}

.square-icon {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: url(images/zoom-icon.png) center center no-repeat; 
  background-color: #FF3860;
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity: 0; 
  transition: display 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
```